# Does Microsoft's Face API require Azure?

Tags: api, azure, face-recognition

I would like to implement Microsoft's [Face API](http://aka.ms/faceapi), but the sign-up link leads to Microsoft Azure.  Does that mean I have to be a paying Azure Cloud customer to use it?  Would that also mean it's not possible to use on a site running on a Linux server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Face API is in the Azure Market Place.  It's free and here are the details:

> The free offer provides all Face API operations that include face
> detection, face verification, similar face searching, face grouping,
> and person identification. With this free plan, calling to the Face
> APIs limits to 20 transactions per minute and 5000 transactions per
> month.

After that, a primary and secondary key is created.  Here is the help documents link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/face/

You can sign-up for Azure's free trial, and utilize the market place.

This is a REST API, so you shouldn't have problems with your Linux server.

Comment: Thank you!  Can't upvote your answer yet, I'm too new :)

Comment: I will up vote your question, because I am sure many people have this question when it relates to Azure market place.

Comment: but it does ask for the Payment information in page https://account.windowsazure.com/SignUp, and doesn't accept my virtual credit card. I have a Dreamspark account and login with it to https://portal.azure.com but then couldn't find Face API. This is my first time with Microsoft products and this is very discouraging.

Comment: I resolved upper problem: in http://portal.azure.com, I tried to install a VM then it gave me a warning to sign up, and followed the link there. Not it gave me several options including 'Dreamspark', 'Free Trial' and so on. When I choose Dreamspark, it created with free plan. Ahh Microsoft you still love in challenging way.

Comment: Is that 5000 transactions means that I can access the api 5000 times .. get and post?

Comment: generally speaking, a transaction for a REST API is a call to the API.  Based on the limitations provided by this without a way to pay for overage, I wouldn't add this into a production model.  It would be fun to play with, but that's where I would draw the line.

Comment: @Mustafa how did you "tried to install a VM"? For me, it says I need to upgrade to premium.

Comment: Market place -> Virtual machines -> and choose one. After all I didn't get the api btw, it became boring and I postpone to handle to another time  @DemCodeLines